# Audio player on Android suitable for manual transcription

Tags: android, audio

I want to perform [transcription](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_%28service%29) of sound files. *Transcription* refers to the manual process of listening to recorded speech and transcribe it into a written text document.

Is there an audio player app for Android tablets, that:

- allows slowing down audio playback without loss in quality and pitch,
- has shortcut buttons for rewind and forwarding,
- is able to set options for shortcut buttons to rewind or forward *X* seconds.

I'm looking for something similar to [Play it slowly](http://29a.ch/playitslowly/) for Ubuntu or a tool with even more functions.

Comment: Do you need the tool to have a text input component as well? Or at least be usable in the background while you type using an independent text app? Or will you actually type on another computer, meaning that the "play slow" app can monopolize the Android device's screen if it wants? Also, what is your budget?

Answer (score 1):

I use Smart Audiobook Player to listen to audiobooks, podcasts and my own voice recordings but it has the features you mention so maybe it's just what you need for manual transcription.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Sure: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer&hl=en_CA

Answer (score 0):

FTW Transcriber has an Android app.  I've been very happy with the desktop version, and hope to switch to Android soon.  Transcription can be done with the on-screen or an external keyboard.  However, it doesn't look like it supports use of a footpedal (unlike the desktop version, which does).  That last point might prevent me from using it.  Hotkeys for playback slow me down.

Comment: Please add a link. I cannot find *what* software you mean.